# How can I make remote notifications backward compatible?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have a remote push notification that gets directly displayed in the notification drawer. Now there is a requirement that we need to change the notification content before it gets displayed in the notification drawer. The problem here is, that if we try to do this, an app with an old build version will stop receiving the notifications which we don't want. What can we do such that, the old app keep on receiving the notifications and newer apps get the notification data changed by the client and then get displayed on the notification drawer?

Comment: What exactly prevents visibility in older versions? To edit a notification, you need it to have (1) the `mutable-content` key, (2) the `alert` (which I believe you've had), and an extension (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications). If you want to customize notifications appearance, you'll also need a notification `category` and another extension (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications). Nothing from these should break anything.

Comment: @lazarevzubov so in the current notification, we are not making it a silent notification. But for a new notification, I was planning to use silent notification with content-available = 1.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make the same notification visible and invisible. Why do you want that?